# Como sobreescribir un archivo existente en excel desde un data frame en R o añadir una columna a un archivo

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

Holi, estoy intentando agregar una nueva columna sobre un archivo existente de excel. La lógica detras de mi código es: abrir un df con el archivo base, combinar el df con los datos del dia de hoy y guardar el df combinado como archivo base, para luego hacer mañana lo mismo ya incluyendo los datos del dia anterior. Hasta ahora intenté usar [`write.xlsx()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/2.0.1/topics/write.xlsx)

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df_FINAL,"C:...base_FCI.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1", row.names=FALSE)
```

y también probé con [`saveWorkbook()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.4/topics/saveWorkbook)

```
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,"C:\\Users\\...\base_FCI.xlsx" )
```

Pero siempre recibo el error:

> Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) :
> File already exists

Que es exactamente lo que quiero hacer!

Otra opción también es añadir al excel la columna con la información nueva y guardarlo pero tampoco encuentro un método que me funcione.

Es un problema super bobo pero leí montones de posts y ninguno da en la tecla con lo que necesito

Alguna idea de que se puede hacer?

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor de `file` y de `overwrite`? Debería ser algo tipo `saveWorkbook(wb, file = "saveWorkbookExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Con la función **write.xlsx()** de **openxlsx** no debería darte problemas. Te muestro un ejemplo que funciona de forma correcta.

- Este es mi archivo excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Este es el código que he empleado para el ejemplo:

```html
 
  library("readxl")

  df <- read_excel("Libro1.xlsx")

  df["Producto"][1] <- "Aspiradora" 
  df["Tienda"] <- c("MediaMarkt","Philips","Samsung","MediaMarkt")

  library("openxlsx")

  write.xlsx(df, "Libro1.xlsx")
```

He modificado el valor de una celda que ya existía y he añadido una columna nueva. Al escribir el nuevo archivo excel se sobreescribe directamente.

Espero haberte ayudado!!